# Postgres: Levenshtein Error

Tags: postgresql, levenshtein-distance

I am getting an error when I try to run a levenshtein function against a postgres database.

```
    ERROR: function levenshtein(text, text) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 152
ERROR: function levenshtein(text, text) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 152
```

This is using the example from postgres [website](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/fuzzystrmatch.html) :

```
SELECT levenshtein('GUMBO', 'GAMBOL');
```

Any reason why?

Comment: fuzzymatch is an extension on postgres that needs to be installed.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createextension.html